# 2015 VW Golf TSI Standard accelerating automatically

Tags: vw, golf, cruise-control, acceleration

The car keeps accelerating after shifting to 3rd/4th gear at random times. I would shift, take my foot off the pedal and the speed would, in one occasion, accelerate to 40kmh and maintain speed.

The cruise control is not turned on. Nothing is pressing down the gas pedal. You can hear the engine accelerate and there is 3 small squealing sounds coming from underneath the car when this happens. Only 3, not more.

The dealership told me that they have found 0 issues with it and asked if I've driven standard before...

Any insight is welcomed!

Comment: Only insight I can give you is to take it to a different dealership for diagnosis. Also, if they will let you, show them exactly what is going on. If you don't get satisfaction, take it up the chain the VW hierarchy for resolution.

Comment: Agree with @Paulster2. If the car is this new it has to be covered by warranty and VW has to hear about it. Don't be dissuaded by dealership claims that the vehicle is fine, since they need to see the issue to understand what's going on. Keep on reminding them that unintended acceleration is a real danger.

Answer (score 2):

I Think this is normal behaviour of a car which has upwards of 150/170hp.

When you are in your 3rd or 4th gear your speed should be more than 40kmph below that the car might stall.

The ECU is detecting the imminent stall and compensating by increasing the rpm and the speed of the vehicle , you do not need to press the accelerator for this to happen. Usually the acceleration should stop after a certain speed is reached. If the RPM reaches more than 2500-3000 then you have an issue.

Basically what I mean is that you are in low speed at high gear shift down and this should not happen.

Note: you can notice this more predominantly on diesel engine since they have more torque this is much more noticeable, you can drive them without pressing the accelerator basically.

Comment: Agreed; the ECU will try and correct RPM and would rather increase throttle than stall.  This is how I managed to drive a car with a snapped throttle cable back home.